# "Completely" readonly radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know `return false;` makes radio button readonly.

But I noticed when click the element, it looks be pushed.
(e.g. IE11: *radio button become black while keep clicking.*)

Is it possible to make radio button "completely" readonly ?
Or it can but too troublesome ?

Comment: are you looking for `disabled` property.

Comment: I'm not looking for disabled, just readonly.They are not same mean, aren't it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a [radio button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-%28type=radio%29) readonly. The `readonly` attribute is the way to make controls readonly, but is not permitted (or supported) for radio buttons.

Note that the `disabled` attribute has a different meaning: in addition to preventing the user from changing the value, it makes the control inactive so that it does not contribute to the form data and it is visually greyed out.

Consider describing why you would want to use a readonly radio button. The underlying problem is probably solvable, even though this assumed approach is not feasible.

Comment: I know radio button doesn't have readonly attribute. But I wanna preview form, and use "return false;". Then I noticed wrote in question.

Comment: For a preview in which data cannot be changed, you should not use a form at all but include the *data to be submitted* nicely formatted. If the data itself needs to be included on the same page, use hidden fields.

Comment: Preview is NOT for data, it's for form ! User can put input elements in field freely, then I need preview for show how is the form.

Comment: @user3273956, I cannot imagine why you or the user would need to “preview the form”. The form, with its filled-in data, is available on the screen. In what sense should it be “previewed”, if it’s not for viewing the data as it will be submitted?

Comment: OK, then simply. I don't want to discuss about "what is radio button" or "why is readonly radio button needed". Just I want to know is way to radio button readonly. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I already answered the question asked: there is no way. I was then just trying to help you out of the corner where you had painted yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `disabled`input attribute.
Disabled input element is unusable and un-clickable.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioname" disabled/> Option 1
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/jda0p0sa/)

Comment: Maybe not an issue but then element is greyish

Comment: Yes, Disabled inputs color should be little fad out.